# Google App Engine (version 1.9.30) API for uploading files in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

When running the following code

```java
private final GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(new RetryParams.Builder().retryMinAttempts(0).retryMaxAttempts(1).build());

public void upload(String bucketName, String objectName, String mime, String name, byte[] content) throws Exception {
    GcsOutputChannel oc = gcsService.createOrReplace(new GcsFilename(bucketName, objectName), new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType(mime).build());
    oc.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(content));
    oc.close();
}
```

I get the exception below:

```
com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.NonRetriableException: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException: The Files API is disabled. Further information: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/files_api
```

I am using, App Engine SDK version 1.9.30, App Engine GCS Client version 0.5.
I found that the File API has been disabled by Google App Engine services.

The above code works fine with App Engine SDK version 1.9.25.

Is there any other solution for uploading files in App Engine?

Comment: The above code works fine with App Engine SDK version : 1.9.25